# Wi-Fi connection not visible

Tags: wifi-configuration, dell-vostro

I am using Dell Vostro Nseries laptop. the system doesn't connect to the wireless connection instead there is a X sign. But works fine with the cable. How can I use the internet with my WiFi connection?

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- Wireless is turned off. **Solution**: look on the keyboard for a key that should turn it on. Or go to *Control Panel => Network and Internet => Network Connections*, look for your wireless connection, right-click its icon and select *Enable*.
- The Wireless Local Area Network card driver is not installed. **Solution**: head over to  [Dell's website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-1100/drivers), select your product and download the appropriate driver, and install it.
- The Wireless Local Area Network card (WLAN or wireless) is malfunctioning. **Solution**: physically replace the card

Comment: it automatically stopped working and showed the X sign. It was working fine like a hour ago.

Comment: @Abhi maybe you accidentally turned Airplane Mode? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-is-airplane-mode

Comment: i am using windows 7.

Comment: the troubleshoot shows that "the windows wireless service is not running in this computer"

Comment: Try this: 1. Click Start, type services.msc and hit enter.
2. Locate WLAN AutoConfig service, double click on it to open its properties window.
3. Under General tab, change the Startup type to Automatic and click Start button.
4. Click Apply and then ok. (from Microsoft Community website)

Comment: error while applying.

Comment: Is Windows updated with the latest updates? They usually solve many issues.

Comment: it was already in automatic though.

Comment: my windows is not up to date. Does that also cause problems regarding wifi and internet??

Comment: Yes it could be the problem. Try updating Windows and see if it helps.

Comment: A simple restart might have solved it.   If windows was on auto-update tho and the computer was not up to date then I would definitely run a malware scanner like malwarebytes